# How to get file mode in ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, io

I'm new to ruby file IO. I have a function that takes a `File` parameter, and I need to make sure that the file is in read-only mode.

```
def myfunction(file)
    raise ArgumentError.new() unless file.kind_of?(File)

    #Assert that file is in read-only mode
end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you want `file.kind_of?(File)` in case `file.class == IO`. See [Object#kind_of?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-kind_of-3F). You could rule out write-only with test `file.readpartial(0) rescue false`, which returns an empty string (truthy) if reading is permitted; else returns `false`. Not quite what you want and very hackish.  I'm not sure why you want to test this, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `file.readable?`, which returns true or false.

Please check [this link.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-readable-3F)

Comment: Please note that the `readable?` and `writable?` methods refer to disk permissions, not ruby File I/O. `f = File.open("tmp/readable", "r"); File.readable?(f.path)` returns `true` for an existing file on disk that has permissions for the current user.

Answer (score 2):

So all you need is 'make sure make sure that the file is in read-only mode', why not just set it as readonly with [FileUtils.chmod](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-chmod).

Or if actually you just want to test if it is readonly, use `File.writeable`?

Comment: The file may be able to have write permissions on disk while the ruby script / app may want to verify that the open file handler is only in read mode (unclear why but that is my read of the question). So I don't think we want to chmod or even make decisions based on filesystem permissions for this questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to raise an error, you can use `reopen`, I think something like:

`file = file.reopen(file.path, "r")`

I can't find a way to otherwise verify that there isn't a write stream, but here's a bit of a hack that will work. Although I don't like exception throwing being used in the expected path, you could use `close_write`:

```
begin
  file.close_write
  # you could actually raise an exception here if you want
  # since getting here means the file was originally opened for writing
rescue IOError
  # This error will be raised if the file was not opened for
  # writing, so this is actually the path we want
end
```